# insert NaNs where needed in matlab

Tags: matlab, insert

i have the following three vectors and i want to insert `NaNs` into `B` where `A` misses the data points in `An`. So my `Bn` should be `[0.1;0.2;0.3;NaN;NaN;0.6;0.7]`. How can i get the Bn? Thanks.--Jackie

`A=[1;2;3;6;7];
An=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7];
B=[0.1;0.2;0.3;0.6;0.7];`

Comment: Will the vector `A` always be a subset of `An`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay so first off, you cant store the string 'NaN' into one cell of a matrix, it must be stored into a cell array.
The code snip below gives you your solution, if cell array is an okay output.
Please let me know any questions or concerns you might have.*

Forget the italic parts, Thanks David K.

```
   % NaN solution for Jackie

   A=[1;2;3;6;7]; An=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]; B=[0.1;0.2;0.3;0.6;0.7];

   len = max(length(A),length(An))
   Bn = zeros(len,1);

   k = 0; % adjust the index so that you don't call B outside of its size

   for i =1 :len
       ind= A(An(i)==A);
       if isempty(ind) ==1
       Bn(i) = nan(1,1)
       k = k+1;
       else
       Bn(i) = B(i-k)
       end
   end
```

Comment: Yes, you most definitely can put `NaN` within a vector. `NaN` means "Not a Number", and is not the character array `'NaN'`

Comment: Thanks David K.  Here is a code that does what you need with only vectors